# MySQL : Can I use one SELECT ... FOR UPDATE to "protect" multiple tables? ( LOCKING )

Tags: mysql, select, transactions, locking, innodb

I'm reading the MySQL docs for hours but I still cannot answer to myself a couple of pretty simple questions... :(

Here is my (simplified) scenario: I have two tables in a database: `tablea` and `tableb`, both tables use the InnoDB storage engine. `tablea` (which is my main table) has a PRIMARY index (`id`) with autoincrement. Now here is what I want to achieve and please keep in mind that the following business logic can be and will be run concurrently:

I start a transaction:

`START TRANSACTION
BEGIN`

then I check if an id exists in `tablea` if yes, I SELECT the row FOR UPDATE, let's call the id I am looking for myid :

`` SELECT `id` FROM `tablea` WHERE `id`='myid' FOR UPDATE; ``

if the above SELECT returns no rows, I simply ROLLBACK the transaction and exit from my function. In other words I'm done when myid is not present in `tablea`.
On the other hand when myid exists then first I need to update some values in `tablea`:

`` UPDATE `tablea` SET `somefield`='somevalue' WHERE `id`='myid'; ``

then I need to check if myid also exists in `tableb`:

`` SELECT * FROM `tableb` WHERE `id`='myid' FOR UPDATE; ``

my first question is about the above SELECT statement: Is it okay to do another SELECT FOR UPDATE here (on `tableb`) ??? Or "FOR UPDATE" is not needed here when dealing with `tableb`, because I already started a transaction and also acquired a lock based on a row in `tablea` ??? Can someone please answer this?

The last SELECT statement above either returns a row from `tableb` (and locks that row for update) or it turns out that myid does not exist in `tableb`.
When myid is present in `tableb` then I just need to update some values in that row, it's simple:

`` UPDATE `tableb` SET `somefieldintableb`='somevaluefortableb' WHERE `id`='myid'; ``

On the other hand when myid is not in `tableb` I need to insert it, and here comes my 2nd question: Should I lock `tableb` before I issue my INSERT INTO statement, like this:

`` LOCK TABLES `tableb` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `tableb` (`id`,`somefieldintableb`) VALUES ('myid','somevaluefortableb');
UNLOCK TABLES `tableb`; ``

and then finally, I do:

`COMMIT`

My goal is this: Since the above described function (with the MySQL transaction) will run in many instances in parallel, I want to prevent any of those instances updating the same row in either `tablea` or `tableb` at the same time. I also want to prevent double-insertion of myid into `tableb`, hence I thought about using LOCK TABLES when myid was not found in `tableb`.

So I have two questions: Should I do a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE within my already started transaction when I want to update `tableb` or locking `tableb` with SELECT ... FOR UPDATE is unnecessary, because holding the lock on `tablea` already "protects" `tableb` too from simultaneous UPDATEs in this case ??? Thanks to the way I started my transaction, I mean.

2nd question: When I need to INSERT a new row into `tableb` should I lock the whole table for that insertion? Or is that something that is totally unnecessary in this case? (Do I need LOCK TABLES `tableb` or not?)

I would appreciate if an expert can answer these two questions for me, because reading the various docs and examples online simply won't help me answering these questions. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT a.`id` AS a_id, b.`id` AS b_id 
FROM `tablea` AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN `tableb` AS b ON a.id=b.id
WHERE a`id`='myid' 
FOR UPDATE;
```

Now you have row locks on both tablea and tableb *if* rows exist. If the SELECT returns nothing, you know the id is not present in tablea. If the SELECT returns a row with a value for a_id, but a NULL for b_id, then you know it's present in tablea and not in tableb.

If the row is present in both tables, this locks rows in both tables simultaneously. If you do it in two steps, you might risk a race condition and deadlock.

Try the INSERT and use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO `tableb` (id, somefieldintableb) VALUES ('myid', 'somevaluefortableb') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `somefieldintableb`='somevaluefortableb';
```

If the row with your desired id value is not present, this will insert it. If the row is present, this will update the row. And you're sure to have access to an existing row, because your SELECT FOR UPDATE locked it earlier.

Don't use table locks if you can avoid it. That's a sure way to create a bottleneck in your application.

---

Re your comments:

Yes, you can use extra join conditions for the date column.

You don't have to update *all* the columns when you use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. You can leave most of them alone if the row exists, and just update one, or a few, or whatever.

Also you can reference the value you *tried* to insert.

```
INSERT INTO `tableb` (id, date, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) 
  VALUES ('myid', $a_date, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col4=VALUES(col4);
```

For more details, I recommend reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thanks, Bill! There is a reason I do things in two steps (I mentioned it was just a simplified example). myid in tableb is not unique, instead in tableb these two fields are unique (and this is the PRIMARY index in tableb, no autoincrement there) : `id`,`date` . So in tableb I'll have only one (or zero) id for every day. Can I still use a single SELECT FOR ... UPDATE in this case? Thinking about it, I can probably do it, but I need to add a WHERE clause for the outer join: AND tableb.date=DATE(NOW())  What do you think?

Comment: I also don't want to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE because: when myid exists in tableb (for today's date) then I only need to update a single field in that row in tableb. But when myid is not in tableb (for today's date) yet, then I need to insert a total of 6 field values and to gather those values for the additional 5 fields is an expensive operation in my program. So when possible, I only want to update just one field in tableb, not all 6 of them. (Simplified examples do not work! ;))

Comment: Would this work?
SELECT a.`id` AS a_id, b.`id` AS b_id 
FROM `tablea` AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN `tableb` AS b ON a.id=b.id AND b.date=DATE(NOW())
WHERE a`id`='myid' 
?

Comment: Thanks, BIll! You rock! I think I can get going from here on my own! Just to clarify my second comment: My problem with using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is this: I do not have the values readily available in my program for the other fields, I only have one value for e.g. col4. If I really need to insert a new row then and only then I must collect the data for the other fields and that is a computationally expensive operation in my program. So whenever possible (when row already exists in tableb) I just want to do an UPDATE of that one field. Again, 'cause I do not have the values for other fields

Comment: I see. Okay, that's a valid reason. :)